# Create column of categories from a column of transactions using regular expressions within a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, pandas

I have a csv file containing banking information that I am importing as a pandas DataFrame. I want to create a new column that contains the transaction categories (e.g. income, expense, transfer), created from a dictionary containing regular expressions to apply to the transaction descriptions.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = pd.read_csv("data/transactions.csv", parse_dates=['Date'])
```

Here is ouput of the `data` DataFrame:

```
      Date                  Description   Amount
2016-01-01          checkcard good food   -12.45
2016-01-02              visa peppy lube   -30.34
2016-01-05           deposit bank of me  5000.00
2016-01-05             transfer to bank  2500.00
2016-01-10         gift from aunt sally    25.00
```

Here are the regular expressions:

```
income = re.compile('.*deposit|gift.*')
expense = re.compile('good food|.*peppy lube.*')
transfer = re.compile('.*transfer.*')
```

And here is the dictionary:

```
catdict = {income: 'income',
           expense: 'expense',
           transfer: 'transfer'}
```

I want code that creates a new column named `Category` that uses the regular expressions to assign the values of the dictionary to rows where the `Description` column matches one of the regular expressions, so the result would be:

```
      Date                  Description   Amount  Category
2016-01-01          checkcard good food   -12.45   expense 
2016-01-02              visa peppy lube   -30.34   expense
2016-01-05           deposit bank of me  5000.00    income
2016-01-05             transfer to bank  2500.00  transfer
2016-01-10         gift from aunt sally    25.00    income
```

Ideally, this code would also insert 'RECONCILE' in the category column for rows where no matches are found in the regular expressions.

I am new to python, and suspect there a pythonic way to do this I am missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What shall be done with overlapping categories? E.g. a gift from auntie sally (coupon) to go eating with here?

Comment: Great question. Maybe prioritization could be build in by having the highest priority categories come first in the dictionary?

Comment: Unfortunately, `dict` is not ordered. You'll need `OrderedDict` to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function that map a string (description) to a category according to your `regex`'s. The first time it matches a pattern, the function returns the name of that category. It returns 'RECONCILE' if none matches.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def category(s):

    catdict = OrderedDict([(income, 'income'),
                          (expense, 'expense'),
                          (transfer, 'transfer'),
                          ])
    for ptn, name in catdict.iteritems():
        if ptn.search(s):
            return name
    return 'RECONCILE'
```

Then you can apply this function to the 'Description' column.

```
data['Category'] = data.Description.map(category)

print data
```

And this should give you what you want.